# Magnetic force between two magnets

Tags: magnetic-fields

I read that the density of magnetic line shows how strong the magnetic force is a certain place.I saw pictures of magnetic lines between two similiar magnets and the lines were evenly distributed and were all straight except those on edge.

I also saw this picture that shows magnetic field between two magnets.It shows the field have same strenght on the vertical axis from magnet to magnet.

The reason I mention this and the point of my question is,how is this possible? I read that magnetic force increase 4 times if distance is halved,and is decreased to one quarter when distance is doubled.

If we are between two magnets in center then top magnet is pulling us by 100 and botton is pushing by 100.If we get closer to bottom magnet by decreasing the distance to half,the distance to top magnet increase to one and half or 150%.

That means the botton magnet starts pushing 4 times stronger so 400 and the top magnet starts pulling weaker 50 points.This means that the force that was 100 + 100 = 200 when we were in center is now 400 + 50 = 450 or more than double.

How is it possible that the pictures shows that the field between two magnets is same strenght no matter if we move closer to one magnet when my calculations show that the field is weakest in center and gets stronger as we move closer to one of the magnets? It makes no sense to me that the field would be same between magnets.
[image: magnetic field between magnets]

Comment: *I read that magnetic force increase 4 times if distance is halved,and is decreased to one quarter when distance is doubled.* I'm not sure where you heard this, but this simply isn't true.

Comment: Isnt it basic fact of magnetism that magnetic force vs distance follows inverse square law?

Comment: No, you're probably thinking about the force between point charges.  Actually, your reasoning is pretty good: you figured out that the things you thought were true are not consistent, because they lead to a contradiction.   Here is a fact you can work with: there is no net magnetic force on a magnetic object in a uniform magnetic field.  There can be a torque, but no net push or pull.  For there to be a net force, the magnetic field must be *non*uniform.

Comment: the inverse square law comes from monopoles. Electric charges are monopoles that have an inverse square law behavior. There are no  magnetic monopoles in nature, so the forces are the forces between dipoles.  see this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole#Forces_between_two_magnetic_dipoles

Comment: S. McGrew and anna v thank you very much for help but I still dont understand why the field between two magnet is same no matter if you are in center or closer to one of the magnets,I would expect the increase from moving closer to one magnet would be larger amount than the decrease caused by moving away from the other magnet so the magnetic field stenght should rise yet that picture shows it doesnt,why?

Comment: The strength of a bar magnet does decrease when you move along it's axis. Maybe not in an inverse square fashion but it definitely does decrease. You should provide the source of what you were reading.